# VB 6 How to make Custom Collection Class to support For Each

Tags: vb6, enumerate

I've been placed on a project whose client front end is written in VB 6, ack!  I'm trying to develop a custom collection class that supports the For...Each syntax. Is this possible in VB 6? Or am I stuck with using the For..Next with counter to identify the index.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what can I say, gots to pay the mortgage, I'm hoping VB6 devs will become rare like those Cobol devs, then when M$ pulls the plug on the VB 6 runtime, I'll be there to cash in on all the migrations to .net...unless, I've already missed that boat, dang!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The key part is adding this to the custom collection class...

```
Public Function NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = m_Employees.[_NewEnum]
End Function
```

and in the procedure attributes, set the procedure id to -4, like so:
[image]

Ref: http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_custom_collection_with_for_each.html

Comment: It feels wrong to upvote anything related to VB6, but very good answer.  :-)

Comment: I'm upvoting your comment, too funny! I know what you mean, feel bad for Chris

Comment: Because there is `#define DISPID_NEWENUM (-4)` in `colldispid.h` along with `#define DISPID_LISTITEM 0` and `#define DISPID_LISTCOUNT (-531)` but these are not used by VB's `For Each` operator.